# How to get the value from controller to handlebar (handlebar.js javascript templating)?

Tags: javascript, grails, handlebars.js

I have set value in model like this

```
        model.val = 'myval'
    render(view: 'index', model: model)
```

& in gsp is there some way by which I could directly get the value of model something like this?

```
<script id="myTemplate" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
  {{val}}
</script>
```

if I try with `{{${val}}}`  then I get the value but is that right way to do it? I mean expression inside handlebars

Comment: The second way is the correct way to get a value from the model into the page and have it in a handlebars variable.

Comment: so this 1 "{{${val}}}" i could use it, right? ... i haven't seen anywhere expression used inside template so was not sure about that... thanks...

Comment: Correct. It's two things going on there. First the ${val} outputs the value from the model to the GSP then {{thevaluenowinthepage}} is being picked up by handlebars. It looks a bit odd with all the curly braces but it's technically correct. I would consider making a custom tag library <h:output var="val" /> that would do that for me instead. Just so my eyes wouldn't have to suffer reading all of that in the GSP. Personal opinion though.

Comment: Try using: `{{ $val }}` it should work as well. For simple fields you can omit `{}` in groovy. Not sure how it behaves in gsp with handlebars but worth a try for cleaner implementation. ;)

Comment: doesn't seem to work inside gsp with handler.

Answer (score 0):

## server.js

```
const body_data = {
        nodes: [
          {data: {id: 'j', name: 'Jerry'}},
          {data: {id: 'e', name: 'Elaine'}},
          {data: {id: 'k', name: 'Kramer'}},
          {data: {id: 'g', name: 'George'}},
          {data: {id: 'd', name: 'Daniel'}},
          {data: {id: 'r', name: 'Rea'}}
        ],
        edges: [
          {data: {source: 'j', target: 'e'}},
          {data: {source: 'j', target: 'k'}},
          {data: {source: 'j', target: 'g'}},
          {data: {source: 'e', target: 'k'}},
          {data: {source: 'k', target: 'g'}},
          {data: {source: 'd', target: 'g'}},
          {data: {source: 'g', target: 'r'}},
        ]
      };

    res.render('home', {
        nombre: 'Leonardo',
        body_data,
    });
```

## HELPER

```
const hbs = require('hbs');
hbs.registerHelper('muestraData', ( data = {} ) => {
    return JSON.stringify(data);
});
```

## home.hbs

```
<script>
    const data = {{{ muestraData body_data }}};
    console.log(data);
</script>
```